# Error: incompatible size when mutating in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a trouble with the `mutate` function in dplyr and the error says;

```
Error: incompatible size (0), expecting 5 (the group size) or 1
```

There are some previous posts and I tried some of the solutions but no luck for my case.

[group-factorial-data-with-multiple-factors-error-incompatible-size-0-expe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39036198/group-factorial-data-with-multiple-factors-error-incompatible-size-0-expe)

[r-dplyr-using-mutate-with-na-omit-causes-error-incompatible-size-d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30747942/r-dplyr-using-mutate-with-na-omit-causes-error-incompatible-size-d)

[grouped-operations-that-result-in-length-not-equal-to-1-or-length-of-group-in-dp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21737815/grouped-operations-that-result-in-length-not-equal-to-1-or-length-of-group-in-dp)

Here is what I tried,

```
ff <- c(seq(0,0.2,0.1),seq(0,-0.2,-0.1))
flip <- c(c(0,0,1,1,1,1),c(1,1,0,0,0,0))
df <- data.frame(ff,flip,group=gl(2,6)) 

> df
     ff flip group
1   0.0    0     1
2   0.1    0     1
3   0.2    1     1
4   0.0    1     1
5  -0.1    1     1
6  -0.2    1     1
7   0.0    1     2
8   0.1    1     2
9   0.2    0     2
10  0.0    0     2
11 -0.1    0     2
12 -0.2    0     2
```

I want to add new group called `c1` and `c2` based on some conditions as follows

```
 dff <- df%>%
      group_by(group)%>%
      mutate(flip=as.numeric(flip),direc=ifelse(c(0,diff(ff))<0,"backward","forward"))%>%
      spread(direc,flip)%>%
      arrange(group,group)%>%
      mutate(c1=ff[head(which(forward>0),1)],c2=ff[tail(which(backward>0),1)])
```

> Error: incompatible size (0), expecting 5 (the group size) or 1

I also add `do` and tried

```
do(data.frame(., c1=ff[head(which(.$forward>0),1)],c2=ff[tail(which(.$backward>0),1)]))
```

> Error in data.frame(., c1 = ff[head(which(.$forward > 0), 1)], c2 = ff[tail(which(.$backward >  : 
>     arguments imply differing number of rows: 5, 1, 0

but when I only `mutate` `c1` column everything seems to be working. Why?

Comment: last line should be `mutate(c1=head(ff[forward>0], 1), c2 = tail(ff[backward > 0], 1))` (Both give NA though with this example)

Comment: There is no value in group 2 for which `backward` is larger than 0.

Comment: @alistaire Even there is no value I should be able to get at least NA values for empty rows right?

Comment: If you adjust your `mutate` to return NA if the `length` of your computation is 0, yes.

Comment: @alistaire Ok. I got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just expanding on @allistaire's comment.

1. Your specified conditions are the cause of the error. specifically, `tail(which(backward>0),1)`
2. Given code can be optimised to get rid of the `spread()`

you can try

```
dff <- df%>%
  group_by(group)%>%
  mutate(flip=as.numeric(flip),direc=ifelse(c(0,diff(ff))<0,"backward","forward"))%>%
  arrange(group)%>%
  mutate(c1=ff[head(which(direc=="forward" & flip > 0),1)])
```

---

It seems like you are looking to identify influx points where `direction` changes, for each `group`. In this scenario, please clarify exactly how flip is related, or maybe if you change `flip <- c(c(0,0,1,1,1,1),c(1,1,0,0,0,0))` to `flip <- c(c(0,0,1,1,1,1),c(1,1,0,1,1,1))` so that `flip` marks change in direction of `ff` , you can use

```
dff <- df%>%
  group_by(group)%>%
  mutate(flip=as.numeric(flip),direc=ifelse(c(0,diff(ff))<0,"backward","forward"))%>%
  arrange(group)%>%
  mutate(c1=ff[head(which(direc=="forward" & flip > 0),1)]) %>%
  mutate(c2=ff[tail(which(direc=="backward"& flip >0),1)])
```

which gives:

```
Source: local data frame [12 x 6]
Groups: group [2]

      ff  flip  group    direc    c1    c2
   <dbl> <dbl> <fctr>    <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1    0.0     0      1  forward   0.2  -0.2
2    0.1     0      1  forward   0.2  -0.2
3    0.2     1      1  forward   0.2  -0.2
4    0.0     1      1 backward   0.2  -0.2
5   -0.1     1      1 backward   0.2  -0.2
6   -0.2     1      1 backward   0.2  -0.2
7    0.0     1      2  forward   0.0  -0.2
8    0.1     1      2  forward   0.0  -0.2
9    0.2     0      2  forward   0.0  -0.2
10   0.0     1      2 backward   0.0  -0.2
11  -0.1     1      2 backward   0.0  -0.2
12  -0.2     1      2 backward   0.0  -0.2
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But it seems that your solution is not working on my real df. Flip order is very important and must not be changed. When you change to `flip <- c(c(0,0,1,1,1,1),c(1,1,0,1,1,1))`, you are changing the the data frame.

Comment: Why you are changing the `flip` column? It must not be changed and I am still getting error since I cannot change `flip` order in my read df.

Comment: I only changed it as an example. you need to understand the cause of the error here, which is that for `c2`, `direc=="backward" & flip >0` does not satisfy both groups in the example and the resultant vector returned is of a length different than the number of groups.

Answer (score 3):

It might be informative to step through the pipe to see what is going on.

```
df %>%
  group_by(group)%>%
  mutate(flip=as.numeric(flip),direc=ifelse(c(0,diff(ff))<0,"backward","forward"))%>%
  spread(direc,flip)%>%
  arrange(group,group)
# Source: local data frame [10 x 4]
# Groups: group [2]
#       ff  group backward forward
#    <dbl> <fctr>    <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1   -0.2      1        1      NA
# 2   -0.1      1        1      NA
# 3    0.0      1        1       0
# 4    0.1      1       NA       0
# 5    0.2      1       NA       1
# 6   -0.2      2        0      NA
# 7   -0.1      2        0      NA
# 8    0.0      2        0       1
# 9    0.1      2       NA       1
# 10   0.2      2       NA       0
```

BTW: Why `arrange(group,group)`? Doubling the order variable is pointless.

Looking here, you'll see that you have (1) `backward` values that are not greater than 0. When you run something like `which(FALSE)` you get `integer(0)`. This might be a good time to realize that `dplyr` needs the vector length of the rhs to be the same length as the number of rows in the group.

Instead of your `mutate`, I'll show it with a slight modification: return the number of unique values returned in the `which` call for `c2`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(group)%>%
  mutate(flip=as.numeric(flip),direc=ifelse(c(0,diff(ff))<0,"backward","forward"))%>%
  spread(direc,flip)%>%
  arrange(group,group)%>%
  mutate(
    c1 = ff[head(which(forward>0),1)],
    c2len = length(which(backward > 0))
  )
# Source: local data frame [10 x 6]
# Groups: group [2]
#       ff  group backward forward    c1 c2len
#    <dbl> <fctr>    <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
# 1   -0.2      1        1      NA   0.2     3
# 2   -0.1      1        1      NA   0.2     3
# 3    0.0      1        1       0   0.2     3
# 4    0.1      1       NA       0   0.2     3
# 5    0.2      1       NA       1   0.2     3
# 6   -0.2      2        0      NA   0.0     0
# 7   -0.1      2        0      NA   0.0     0
# 8    0.0      2        0       1   0.0     0
# 9    0.1      2       NA       1   0.0     0
# 10   0.2      2       NA       0   0.0     0
```

In order to meaningfully index on `ff`, you need something other than `integer(0)` in your returns.

Comment: I am sorry it seems there is no output for c2? am I right?

Comment: The point is effectively alistaire's, but I wasn't assuming that that was your logic. My answer is strictly answering the question "Why", assuming you could fix the flawed logic.

Comment: (Correction, the point was @Sotos' point.) A common omission in SO questions (hinted at in the [SO help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) under "Verifiable") is to provide a sample of the expected output. Sometimes this can be as easy as generating a static data.frame with the values you expect, or at least what they will look like. Especially with complicated input structures, it almost always benefits everybody if the question is asked with small and representative data; in which case, it is often much easier to dictate what the output should be.